# CSV joining based on keys

Tags: python, csv, inner-join, csvkit

This may be a simple/repeat question, but I could find/figure out yet how to do it.

I have two csv files:

**info.csv:**

```
"Last Name", First Name, ID, phone, adress, age X [Total age: 100] |009076

abc, xyz, 1234, 982-128-0000, pqt,

bcd, uvw, 3124, 813-222-1111, tre, 

poi, ccc, 9087, 123-45607890, weq,
```

and then

**age.csv:**

```
student_id,age_1

3124,20

9087,21

1234,45
```

I want to compare the two csv files, based on the columns "`id`" from **info.csv** and "`student_id`" from **age.csv** and take the corresponding "`age_1`" data and put it into the  "`age`" column in **info.csv**.

So the final output should be:

**info.csv:**

```
"Last Name", First Name, ID, phone, adress, age X [Total age: 100] |009076
 abc, xyz, 1234, 982-128-0000, pqt,45
 bcd, uvw, 3124, 813-222-1111, tre,20
 poi, ccc, 9087, 123-45607890, weq,21
```

I am able to simply join the tables based on the keys into a **new.csv**, but can't put the data in the columns titles "`age`". I used "`csvkit`" to do that.

Here is what I used:

```
csvjoin -c 3,1 info.csv age.csv > new.csv
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
import csv

info = list(csv.reader(open("info.csv", 'rb')))
age = list(csv.reader(open("age.csv", 'rb')))

def copyCSV(age, info, outFileName = 'out.csv'):
    # put age into dict, indexed by ID
    # assumes no duplicate entries

    # 1 - build a dict ageDict to represent data
    ageDict = dict([(entry[0].replace(' ',''), entry[1]) for entry in age[1:] if entry != []])

    # 2 - setup output
    with open(outFileName, 'wb') as outFile:
        outwriter = csv.writer(outFile)
        # 3 - run through info and slot in ages and write to output
        # nb: had to use .replace(' ','') to strip out whitespaces - these may not be in original .csv
        outwriter.writerow(info[0])
        for entry in info[1:]:
            if entry != []:
                key = entry[2].replace(' ','')
                if key in ageDict: # checks that you have data from age.csv
                    entry[5] = ageDict[key]
            outwriter.writerow(entry)

copyCSV(age, info)
```

Let me know if it works or if anything is unclear. I've used a dict because it should be faster if your files are massive, as you only have to loop through the data in age.csv once.

There may be a simpler way / something already implemented...but this should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Pandas` and update the `info dataframe` using the `age` data. You do it by setting the index of both data frames to  `ID` and `student_id` respectively, then update the age column in the `info dataframe`. After that you reset the index so `ID` becomes a column again.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

info = StringIO("""Last Name,First Name,ID,phone,adress,age X [Total age: 100] |009076
abc, xyz, 1234, 982-128-0000, pqt,
bcd, uvw, 3124, 813-222-1111, tre, 
poi, ccc, 9087, 123-45607890, weq,""")


age = StringIO("""student_id,age_1
3124,20
9087,21
1234,45""")

info_df = pd.read_csv(info, sep=",", engine='python')
age_df = pd.read_csv(age, sep=",", engine='python')

info_df = info_df.set_index('ID')
age_df = age_df.set_index('student_id')
info_df['age X [Total age: 100] |009076'].update(age_df.age_1)
info_df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
info_df
```

outputs:

```
    ID      Last Name   First Name      phone           adress  age X [Total age: 100] |009076
0   1234    abc         xyz              982-128-0000   pqt     45
1   3124    bcd         uvw              813-222-1111   tre     20
2   9087    poi         ccc              123-45607890   weq     21
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, cause in my actual CSV, the last column header have space in it. It is like "age students|all". 
So when I replace this line of your code: info_df.age.update(age_df.age_1)
with the actual header, it gives me syntax error.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the actual header as well as the syntax error you are getting. Two things, you can rename the header in the csv file or just get the column names using `df.columns` to see the actual names of the columns.

Comment: This is the column name that needs to be updated:
u'age X [Total age: 100] |009076'

Comment: That's a weird name for a column. Why dont rename the column of the csv to something more common?

Comment: I can't rename the names of the columns, as it won't be uploaded back to ther server again. The headers are some sort of identifier for the uploading back to the server. 
I did try this:
  df1_key.columns[9].update(df2_key.columns[1])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: Just update your question with the actual column names and it will be easier to update the answer. Im a bit confused by it

Comment: Updated the Column names

Comment: @user3285014 Its is working with the new age column name

Comment: Thanks a lot...:-)